# Build Checkbox list programmatically using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to populate checkbox from value return in   `$domain = Get-MsolDomain` which return domains available then generate the checkbox based on the value return and excluding the value from @mail. Thank you

Here is the code that i have so far:

```
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'} 
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Loading SharePoint PowerShell Snapin"
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}
Import-Module MSOnline
$credentials = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credentials

$unlicensedUsersBatch500 = Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly -MaxResults 500



[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,700) 
$Form.text ="Office 365 Licence Activation" 

############################################## Start group boxes

$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,20) 
$groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,100) 
$groupBox.text = "Availabe Office 365 Domains:" 
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)


$Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Checkboxes.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 


$domain = Get-MsolDomain



foreach ($a in $domain)
{    

    for ($i=1;$i -lt 6; $i++) 
    {
    $Checkboxes.Text = $a.Name
    }
}
$groupBox.Controls.Add($Checkboxes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as follows. Note that I created and populated $domain for the sake of testing, so you will need to replace that with your call to `Get-MsolDomain`.
Small plus, the size of the groupbox will grow automatically, based on the number of elements in $domain.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,700) 
$Form.text ="Office 365 Licence Activation" 

############################################## Start group boxes

$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,20)  
$groupBox.text = "Availabe Office 365 Domains:" 
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)


$Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Checkboxes.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 

#$domain = Get-MsolDomain
$domain = @()
$domain += @{"Name"="domain1"}
$domain += @{"Name"="domain2"}
$domain += @{"Name"="domain3"}

$Checkboxes = @()
$y = 20
foreach ($a in $domain)
{    
    $Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $Checkbox.Text = $a.Name
    $Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,$y) 
    $y += 30
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Checkbox) 
    $Checkboxes += $Checkbox
}
$groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,(40*$checkboxes.Count)) 
$form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```